# Creating a mock API for third party library in statically typed language?

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, interface

I have an application in VB/C# .NET which needs to interact with a third party API, but I would like to interface it out so I can use a mock API for testing purposes. Here are example API calls I would use in code:

```
RelayClient.AuthenticateUser(username, password, request, sessionID)
RelayClient.GetUserInfo(sessionID)
```

A few problems I am facing:

1. RelayClient is NonInheritable/Static.
2. RelayClient doesn't implement any interfaces.
3. The API client library is closed source.

Is there any standard way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: this is a long shot, but if there are classes in your target assembly that inherit from MarshalByRefObject then many free mocking frameworks (Moq, RhinoMocks, etc.) can mock them, even if they are sealed. unfortunately they still won't be able to mock static classes though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to make your code work against 'middle-man' non-static classes, which internally use the static classes from your 3rd party API. You then mock out these 'middle-man' classes for your unit tests.

Something like... (untested code)

```
// your consuming class
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly RelayClientManager manager;

    public MyClass(RelayClientManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public UserInfo GetUserInfo(int sessionID)
    {
        return manager.GetUserInfo(sessionID);
    }    
}

// 'middle-man' class
public class RelayClientManager
{
    public UserInfo GetUserInfo(int sessionID)
    {
        return RelayClient.GetUserInfo(sessionID);
    }
}

// unit test (using xUnit.net and Moq)
[Fact]
public static void GetsUserInfo()
{
    // arrange
    var expected = new UserInfo();
    var manager = new Mock<RelayClientManager>();
    manager.Setup(x => x.GetUserInfo(0)).Returns(expected);
    var target = new MyClass(manager);        

    // act
    var actual = target.GetUserInfo(0);

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I implemented, except I manually create the mock classes and populate with fixed data. I will check out xUnit.net and Moq and see how those work.

Comment: just to clarify - xUnit.net is a unit testing framework and Moq is a mocking framework.  these two are my respective favourites but the approach I've described will work just as well with many other alternatives, e.g. NUnit and RhinoMocks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to roll your own abstraction, have a look at [TypeMock Isolator](http://site.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product/)- it uses profiler hooks to do runtime class-level mocking of pretty much anything, whether you own it or not. It actually does a runtime substitution of the type implementation and intercepts all the calls (eg, you don't need to subclass the type- as far as the CLR is concerned, you ARE the type).

It's commercial, but they do have a free trial. Depending on how big the thing you need to mock is, the $799 can be well worth the time abstracting/wrapping the entire API surface if it's not interface-based.